# accesskey VS navigator keyboard shortcut

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard-shortcuts, access-keys

It seems to be a recurrent tricky question but I still don't have a fix nor workaround for it:

***Is there a way to intercept accesskeys before keyboard shortcuts?***

I need to use accesskeys on my *favorites* navigator IE and also FF, but I don't wan't to consider existing shortkeys as reserved. Otherwise it doesn't leave a lot of possibilities (currently I only use numbers).

Note: by accesskey, I mean the `accesskey` html attribute.

Any idea ?
Flash apps can do it, so what about JavaScript ?

---

For example here is an *accessible* control:

```
<button onclick="alert('Hello');" accesskey="F">Alt+F to activate</button>
```

When I try to activate it I just open *File* menu :'(

Comment: **NOTE** You won't meet the problem with firefox since accesskeys are activated with *Shift+Alt+[key]* and menu with *Alt+[key]*.

Comment: If you use keydown handlers, you can block the default behavior. With access keys, my experience (from around 2 years ago) is that you need to make sure they don't conflict with menu options, which is not very doable

Comment: I hope the answer is no.  I don't want any old web-page to be able to hi-jack my keyboard commands.  When I strike *Alt+F* I want the File menu.

Answer (score 1):

John Resig (the creator of jQuery) has been working on a "hotkey" addon for jQuery which should do what you are looking for.

https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

I know this isn't a 'jQuery question', and adding a framework for something 'small' isn't ideal, but it should offer a solution.  On the other hand, you can always look over how he did it for inspiration.

Comment: It could be a jQuery solution. I read about this plugin but it doesn't fit, as the addendum says default behaviour will also be fired: "Others, (IE) either let you handle built-in short-cuts, but will add their functionality after your code has executed."

Answer (score 0):

This will, obviously, depend on the browser. For the "big three":

- Firefox: menu shortcuts use <kbd>Alt</kbd>, "accesskey" shortcuts use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>, so there is no conflict.
- Google Chrome: both types of shortcuts use <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and menu shortcuts take precedence, *but*, if there is a conflict, "accesskey" shortcuts use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>, so they are still accessible. See my answer to [Disable Alt functions (shortcuts) in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113563/disable-alt-functions-shortcuts-in-google-chrome/31827736#31827736) for an example.
- Internet Explorer: both types of shortcuts use <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and "accesskey" shortcuts take precedence - just what you want :-).

In short:
No, there is no way to override the browser behavior in Javascript (and arguably that would be a security vulnerability), but all browser have ways to handle these conflicts.

Comment: And why is in "big three" IE, not Opera? :o)

Comment: @Legionar: To be honest, because I did not have an installation of Opera handy (just like with Konqueror, Safari, Android Browser...) :-). Feel free to edit the answer if you have information on other browsers.