# Disable Alt functions (shortcuts) in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I use the following code (as shortcut) to redirect users on my feedback page.

```
<a href='/feedback/' accesskey='f'>feedback</a>
```

But this code does not work in Google Chrome because when user presses <kbd>Alt + F</kbd> it will open the Google Chrome menu bar.

How do I disable those 'shortcuts'?

It can be jQuery, javascript...

Note: I have written a javascript code that redirects, but it firstly opens the Chrome menu bar then does its job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers that allow this theoretically expose a security vulnerability.  If it's possible to override "system" behaviors, you could hijack the users browser.  It would be able to pop up a fake "File" menu that simulates the real one and makes the user think they are interacting with their own local machine instead of a web site.

Because of this it's impossible in most modern browsers.

Answer (score 2):

There are certain special keys that are reserved and <kbd>Alt+F</kbd> is one of them but it will really vary between browsers and operating systems. Here's a [`good article`](http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/accesskey#browserconflicts).

Answer (score 2):

In Google Chrome (tested in V44), the modifier key to access `accesskey` keyboard shortcuts is <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

However, if the key **conflicts with a browser shortcut**, it is accessed with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>. So the solution you posted works, but only using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Example:

- the first link is accessed with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+f (conflict with menu shortcut)
- the second link is accessed with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+a (no conflict)

```html
<h1>Links with accesskey attribute</h1>

<a href='http://www.example.org/' accesskey='f'>
Link to www.example.org (accesskey: f)
</a>
<p/>
<a href='http://apache.org/' accesskey='a'>
Link to apache.org (accesskey: a)
</a>
```

Incidentally, I prefer the solution Firefox uses, which is to always use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> for these shortcuts. This is more consistent for users than Chrome's behavior (though the Chome devs may have had their reasons).

---

*Note:* The above is valid on Windows and Linux. AFAIK, Chrome on Mac OS X uses different shortcuts.

Comment: Oh wow. I never realized that Alt+Shift+(key) was _not_ the primary method for accesskeys. Because on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Holm) they label all their accesskeys with [alt-shift-(key)], regardless of a potential conflict.

Comment: Alt+Shift+F does not ever work in Chrome for Linux, Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. And there is no solution for this.

Comment: @WoodrowShigeru: Strange. I just tested with Chrome 65 on Debian, and Alt+Shift+F does work for me in the testcase above.

Comment: I have Chrome 71 and this testcase doesn't work. Maybe it's a bug the Google devs have added.

Comment: @WoodrowShigeru: Just re-tested with Chrome 71 - still works for me. Note, though, that there seems to be some problem with keyboard focus handling. I had to click into the example page, e.g. on the heading, for the key shortcuts to work. Also, if you trigger the menu with Alt-F, you need to click again to correct the keyboard focus. Maybe that's what caused your problem? If not, feel free to ask a new question :-).

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work for me. The Alt+T accesskey does work, but "F" is troublesome. I've even filed an issue on the Chromium Issue Tracker … but it really seems to be a problem exclusive to my machine. Sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, it's probably not a good idea.

But if you're a madlad and you like doing what you want, this will actually work:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.altKey) {
    console.log('yay');
  }
})
```

`e.preventDefault()` needs to be placed at the top of the event handler. This prevents the browser's default behavior (ie., opening menus).

Answer (score 0):

I just found a way how to disable browser functions when user presses <kbd>Alt + other button</kbd>. Javascript can disable this shortcuts by writing at the end of the function `return false`

Example

```
function function1(){/* code goes here */; return false}
```

Comment: can u give an example

Comment: Sorry, can't see how this is an answer.